# Web Page not reloading with XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, web-development-server

While working with XAMPP, my web page does not get reloaded immediately. How to fix it? I tried empty cache and hard reload but neither works.

Comment: have you cheklc the web console in youir browser if there is a problem with, also we cqan't see the source code that you are working on, so read up on debugging, to know what went wrong

Comment: What exact version of xampp and PHP, apache, sql You using?
What message You get?

Comment: m using 8.0.9 version.